# Android Studio syntax highlighting issue

Tags: android-studio

There is an issue with android studio code colouring and Throwable. After I add Throwable anywhere at class, code colouring and syntax check stop working. You can see that below, I wrote from top to bottom and at each step I wrote what happened between commas. I am using Android Studio 4.1 Cannary 8.

[image]

Edit: with java it works normal.